# Как динамично подключить скрипт js странице

Tags: javascript

Вот пытаюсь таким образом подключить динамично скрипт на странице в итоге белый экран получаю

```
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></scr' + 'ipt>');
```

Comment: В консоли браузера какие ошибки?

Comment: @Visman Ничего просто берет стирает всю страницу и вверху этот скрипт, который я пытаюсь подключить а все остальное исчезает

Comment: А обычным способом на страницу вы не пробовали его подключить?

Comment: @Visman нет нужно динамично

Comment: Так через `document.write` это не динамично.  Прочитайте о методе https://learn.javascript.ru/document-write

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Технически, вызвать document.write можно в любое время, однако, когда HTML загрузился, и браузер полностью построил DOM, документ становится «закрытым». Попытка дописать что-то в закрытый документ открывает его заново. При этом все текущее содержимое удаляется.

Что у вас и происходит.

https://learn.javascript.ru/document-write

**UPD**
Вот таким способом можно загрузить скрипт на страницу в любое время

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var newScript = document.createElement('script');
 newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
 newScript.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places';
 document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newScript);
</script>
```