# Как вставить ссылку на JS в другой файл JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

Есть ссылка на документ JS вида:

```
<script charset="UTF-8" src="//cdn.serp.com/4654321324654321346784gfgcb21gfh4t1231b6tsrb1_0.js" async></script>
```

Вставлять такую ссылку в страницы сайта на котором 300 страниц не удобно да и потом не зачем. Возможно ее убрать придется. Ко всем страницам подключены другие JS файлы.

Сам вопрос такой:  Как эту ссылку вставить в файл JS, который уже подключен к странице или страницам?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/448288/186083 только не на страницу, а в скрипт код вставить.

Comment: а что у вас каждая страница в отдельном .html файле?

Comment: Да в отдельном файле и подгружается некотоые элементы на ajax А что такого ? Да и вопрос в другом состоит ? Вас что так это задело ?

Comment: ru.stackoverflow.com/a/448288/186083 только не на страницу, а в скрипт код вставить. – Visman Это я пробовал Да и вариант этот в самом коде html а мне надо в самом файле js Можно конечно его и туда засунуть но он не работает !

Comment: var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'путь к файлу';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);    Тоже не работает

Comment: [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
var importCdn = document.createElement('script');

importCdn.setAttribute('src', '//cdn.serp.com/4654321324654321346784gfgcb21gfh4t1231b6tsrb1_0.js');

document.head.appendChild(importCdn);
```